# Access user info in java from azure access token

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a react front on which I can connect via an azure app.
I get an access token (seems correct), which I would like to use in my requests for a back in java to verify an user and access this data

I tried:

```
public void verifyAzureToken(String tokenToValidate) {

        // source:
    
        //
    
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java
    
        final String clientId = "my_clientId";
    
        final String tenantId = "my_tenantId";
    
        final String clientSecret = "my_clientSecret";
    
        final List<String> scopes =
    
        Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
    
        // final List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("user.read");
    
        // This is the incoming token to exchange using on-behalf-of flow
    
        final String oboToken = tokenToValidate;
    
        final OnBehalfOfCredential credential = new OnBehalfOfCredentialBuilder()
    
                .clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).clientSecret(clientSecret)
    
                .userAssertion(oboToken).build();
    
        if (null == scopes || null == credential) {
    
            // throw new Exception("Unexpected error");
    
            System.out.println("Unexpected error");
    
            return;
    
        }
    
        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
    
                scopes, credential);
    
        final GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
    
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();
    
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=java
    
        com.microsoft.graph.models.User user = graphClient.me()
    
                .buildRequest()
    
                .get();
    
        if (user != null) {
    
            //
    
            https: // learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java
    
            System.out.println(user.givenName);
    
        }
```

and i got:

*com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalInteractionRequiredException: AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - Key was found, but use of the key to verify the signature failed., Thumbprint of key used by client: 'F8A23743D9CD47B6D1A1FC66799A17A9B1D919EC', Found key 'Start=10/02/2022 18:06:49, End=10/02/2027 18:06:49', Please visit the Azure Portal, Graph Explorer or directly use MS Graph to see configured keys for app Id '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'. Review the documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments to determine the corresponding service endpoint and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to build a query request URL, such as 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'].*

I have the same message with the same Thumbprint whatever informations I put in the 3 my_id...
What am I doing so wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> The error usually occurs if you are using **wrong assertion** generated with invalid scopes to get access token in **on-behalf of** flow.

When I tried to get access token with **wrong assertion** via Postman, I too got **same error** as below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <API_appID>
client_secret: <API_secret>
scope: User.Read
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: <assertion with invalid scope>
requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to get access token from **middle-tier API** with exposed API scope for your user and use it as **`assertion`** for the OBO call.

I have one application where I **exposed an API** by adding scope as below:

[image]

Now, I registered one Azure AD application named **`ClientApp`** and granted consent to these **permissions**:

[image]

I generated access token using **authorization code** flow with exposed API scope via Postman like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <client_appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: api://xxxxxxx/access_as_user
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I used above token as **`assertion`** value in **on-behalf of** flow with MS graph scope and got response like this:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <API_appID>
client_secret: <API_secret>
scope: User.Read
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: <paste_above_access_token>
requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I call **/me** endpoint by using above access token, I got response with **`given_name`** successfully:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, try decoding `tokenToValidate` string (user assertion) from your code in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website and check whether  **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims are related to **middle-tier API** or not like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Key was found, but use of the key to verify the signature failed - Microsoft Q&A by **Alfredo Revilla**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/899134/key-was-found-but-use-of-the-key-to-verify-the-sig)